# NO Uncertainties for particles in their own frames!

Tags: reference-frames, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, particle-physics

Well I had this thought experiment in which a particle observes itself, and something like the following is observed.

Taking in mind the uncertainty principle all particles even stopped at 0K jiggle about, but nothing stops us from going into there frame and observing from there. We do just that, we go in the frame of a particle and keep it at the origin, since we are in the frame of the particle it does not move, its entire universe seems to jiggle as from outside frame we would say the particle is jiggling.

So how the principle seems to have failed here? We most definitely know that our particle is motionless at the origin when we see from its own frame, we do not care about the entire universe jiggling about and we notice that the uncertainty principle becomes invalid! Why is such a thing happening? Am I doing something wrong? Or is this a known loophole to the principle?

Comment: The particle's rest frame, if there even is such a thing, is not inertial.

Comment: The uncertainty principle doesn't mean that particles jiggle back and forth. Instead, it places a fundamental (*quantum mechanical*) limit to the precision of our *classical* instruments. And, we're in a *perplexed* state of mind, that we've already been confused by the particle-nature and wave-nature of the so-called *particles*. In such a state, how can we imagine a frame for such an inconceivable thing?

Comment: "the uncertainty principle all particles even stopped at 0K" <- have you ever heard about the zero-point energy?

Comment: Well first things first, I do not understand the downvotes! Now #javier: particles and bodies are supposed to be at rest in their frames thats all I intended to say and use #peanut : how is that inconceivable? I am talking about seeing something from its frame that's all #peter : I have mentioned their jiggling at 0K please read it and quote it completely, the jiggling is what is referred to as zero point energy

Comment: Also will someone please explain how is this not mainstream physics and eligible for closing?

Comment: Yes I'm a bit surprised at the downvotes and votes to close. It seems a fair question to me.

Comment: Not only is this a reasonable questions, but a good answer could be *very good*, indeed.

Answer (score 4):

A 'particle' (in the way that you are thinking about it) is a classical concept. In special relativity, it is possible to go to the rest frame of a particle, but you cannot hope to apply the uncertainty principle.

In quantum mechanics the existence of a 'particle' is described by a *state* $| \psi \rangle$ in the Hilbert space. The classical concepts of energy, momentum and position are then described in terms of linear operators ${\hat H}$, ${\hat p}$ and ${\hat x}$. It is possible to move into the rest frame of a particle here. (There are issues about normalizability of the such a state, but those can be swept under the rug for the level of rigour here.) However, in quantum mechanics the 'rest frame' is the statement that the state satisfies
$$
{\hat H} | \psi \rangle = m | \psi \rangle,~~ {\hat p} | \psi \rangle = 0
$$
The position of the particle is then described by the expection of the ${\hat x}$ operator, $x_0 = \langle \psi | {\hat x} | \psi \rangle$. This quantity *is* going to be a precise number. However, the interpretation of this is **not** that the particle exists at $x_0$. Rather, if one were to measure the position of the particle, it is most likely to be found at $x_0$. More generally, multiple experiments measuring the position of such a particle will yield many different results. The statistical variance of the multiple experimental measurements will satisfy the Uncertainty relation. In this case of course, since $\Delta p = 0$, the variance in $x$ is infinite.

Remember that the uncertainty relation is *not* a statement about the particle jiggling about and thereby providing uncertainties in measurements. Rather, it is a statement about the fundamental breakdown of the concept of a particle, as we are used to thinking about it.

Comment: I know uncertainty principle does not talk of jiggling of atoms, I know that the concept of jiggling and zero point energy is due to it. What I do not understand is how can you say that $ x_0$ would be a precise number and still there would be infinite uncertainty in it? If we are infact in the frame of the particle, we *are* the particle the coordinate system will start with us, how can we possibly change our own position when we always are at origin?

Comment: $x_0$ is the *most likely* measurement. Each measurement in itself is a precise number, but none of them individually tell you where *the particle is* (whatever that means in a quantum theory). All the measurements together build up a statistical distribution of the position of the particle. The variance of this distribution is called $\Delta x$ and this is the quantity that goes into the uncertainty principle, $\Delta x \Delta p \geq \hbar/2$.

Comment: As I explained, in a quantum theory, being in a frame of the particle means being in a frame where its spatial momentum is zero. It does *not* mean going to frame where the particle is fixed at the origin. What is confusing you is that you are thinking of a particle as a point-like object in space. This notion of a particle *does not hold* in a quantum theory.

Comment: I would agree with you that the particle would not be a point like object in quantum physics, but I woukd raise the point that when and if you go and sit on an electron, proton or what have you, would you say it(whatever you say it is) is in many places or one? I hope that you do not mean to say that if I go into the frame of an electron I would be seeing it at a 100 positions at the same time without it ever moving! {It's ok if u did mean to say that}

Comment: What do you mean by *sit on an electron*?? The electron isn't located at any one point. There is _no_ physical point object that one can go sit on and conduct experiments. The electron exists as a wavefunction.

Comment: I would object to your assertion by saying that it exhibits wave-particle duality and is not "just" a wave but a particle just as much as a wave. Still we can talk about some other particle of your choice where you can at least chose a centre of mass to go and sit!

Comment: Let me state this again - You cannot sit on the electron (or any other particle for that matter) because in the rest frame of the electron, there is no sense in which we can define a location for the electron. You might say, "OK, lets measure the location of the electron, then go and sit at that location." However measurement of an identical electron (note that I did not say _same_ electron) from that location will _not_ yield the same answer as before, i.e. identical measurements of the location of identical electrons do not yield the same result.

Comment: To state it the way that you are thinking about this (which is incorrect) - If I sit on the electron (take it to be the origin) and measure its location, I will find that it is _not_ located at the origin. Rather, the location could be anywhere.

Comment: Remember, here we are assuming that sitting on the electron means that it is at rest in my frame. Unfortunately, being at rest and being at a fixed location are _not_ both allowed by quantum mechanics. Only one of the two can be chosen. And again, the reconciliation of this is the fact that particles are not physical point like things that we are used to in classical physics. The mistake you are making is treating a particle like some physical object in space (which is a classical notion) and also applying quantum mechanics to it.

Comment: But that is from a different frame!! In which the electron can atleast move from one location to another, when we go in its frame it **cannot** possible change position. Maybe the idea of going in something like a particle's frame is too radical to explain, but please atleast try to think about what I am saying...

Comment: First of all lets agree that we are going to take a particle and treat it like a particle alone atleast for this thought experiment. Secondly suppose you take a picture of this particle, you get to know the position of this particle but get no idea of its momentum. Lastly imagine instead of taking a picture at a moment you caught onto that particle and held on, now you sit on the origin in that particles frame and although the entire universe moves you don't and hence you have a well defined position and momentum both 0.

Comment: In classical physics - Going to a particle's frame means going to a frame where the momentum of the particle is zero _and_ where it is fixed at the origin. In quantum physics, *this cannot be done!!!!* You **cannot** go to a frame where the particle is at rest _and_ is fixed. You choose _only_ one, and the other _must_ satisfy the uncertainty relation, i.e. you can go to frame where the particles momentum is zero and then its location is not fixed, or you can go to a frame where the particle's location is fixed, but then its momentum is not zero.

Comment: Even in a thought experiment, you cannot treat a particle like a classical particle and then apply quantum mechanics to it!

Comment: But lets follow through with what you just said. Let us treat a particle like a normal particle. Then, YES it is true that in the frame of a particle, one has fixed well-defined position and momentum. But this is not in contradiction to the uncertainty principle because, your thought experiment violates the fundamental assumptions of quantum mechanics and therefore the uncertainty relation *does not apply*.

Comment: Ok, will you explain if I chose a frame in which a particle is at origin and now since I have a location frame, the particle must always be at origin, how can it possibly have any momentum in said frame? Similarly, if I take a frame in which the particle does not move, it just does not move,  wheres it gonna go? Its gonna stay where it was!!

Comment: When you are using the word particle, you mean a classical particle. With that notion in mind, everything that you have said is absolutely correct. I don't challenge anything you have said about a classical particle. But I do have a problem with you trying to apply the principles of quantum mechanics on such a notion of a particle.

Comment: I find it very humorous that you are not challenging and proving me wrong and just saying that whatever I am saying is not applicable! Quantum mechanics does not say (atleast I haven't read) that you can't treat electrons etc as particles! That being said, all I have done is taken a frame lets say momentum 0 frame, and then noticed that now the particle cannot move!! What is that becomes unapplicable here?

Comment: In fact, quantum mechanics says exactly that. You cannot treat electrons are classical particles. The problem I think is more in jargon that is used. When the word 'particle' is used in quantum mechanics, one _usually_ means a state with a well-defined momentum *but not location*. This is in stark contrast to what we mean by a particle in classical mechanics where a particle is an object with well-defined momentum and position. Do not confuse between the two things.

Comment: I would also like to add that I have been challenging your statements. In particular, I am challenging your notion of a particle. I have been trying to explain to you that quantum mechanical particle is not the same as a classical particle.

Comment: Well lets take your definition of particle, it has defined momentum, and it must be someplace at sometime that we cannot possibly measure nevertheless it has mass, it must has some weird shape and volume and even position we cannot measure it without infinitely large uncertainty,  but it **has** some position too, combine this with my comments on dmckee's answer.

Comment: I have to leave somewhere now. But I would love to continue this chat sometime later. It is probably better if we continued it in chat rather than here. Sorry for bailing like this.

Comment: I will leave you with one question that you can think of. You say - "it must be someplace at sometime". Why do to think this is true??? I'm trying to convey to you that precisely this statement is not true.

Comment: If you wish to continue this discussion, please do so in [chat]. Further comments here will be deleted.

Answer (score 3):

Let's think a little bit about what it would mean to place ones self in the rest frame of a particle. That is, I want to outline a procedure for making this so rather than simply assuming it.

- **I boost to the particle's frame**

  I put my lab on a spacecraft, boost to interstellar space and wait of a proton to wander by. When one does I *measure* it's momentum and then design a chase program to bring me into the same frame.

  That measurement entails some uncertainty, or if it does not I must randomize the particles position *any in frame, including it's own*.
- **I stop a particle in the lab**

  Who wants to bother with all that troublesome spaceflight stuff anyway? I'll just stop a particle in the lab and then I'll be in it's rest frame.

  So, I set up some particle detectors around the lab and when the right one comes along (presumably from a beam I designed, but that is a irrelevant detail) I interact with it somehow to bring it to a stop. I know two approaches to this problem.

  First, I could measure it's momentum and hit it with a carefully calibrated hammer (say a tuned photon) to bring it to a stop. That involves *both* the measurement uncertainty and the momentum uncertainty of the photon.

  Second, I could bind it into some kind of trap and then slowly cool the trap. That makes the particle bound and imposes a ground-state energy and consequent momentum uncertainty from the standing wave boundary condition.

So, no matter what you think you have achieved by assuming that you know the rest frame of the particle, there is no operational way to achieve this trick.

Comment: I find this answer extremely interesting and amusing,  but not fulfilling. I saw on horizon a biography sort of einstein in that he imagines (thought experiment) of running alongside sound, he knew that it was not possible, one cannot even run besides sound you can have speeds equivalent to sound but you cant be running besides it. Just similarly I am talking about something...

Comment: ... lets say 3rd procedure(you didn't think of thish)I sit with my lab at any position, and wait for a particle to hit and stick with me, I dont care its position or momentum or that the probability is negligible (its still there though), but as soon as it hits and sticks to me I am onboard, I come to frame where I am at origin and the particle is at rest, this is what I am talking about!

Comment: Then it is bound to you and subject to the same ground-state concerns that I discussed with trapping it.

Comment: How is that so? I would just sit in a high probability region and wait for it for an infinitely long time, why would I be bound by anything? I do not have to care about momentum as it would adjust by conservation of momentum and be 0 anyway in our frame, also I do not have to care about the position as the particle would be coming there at some possible time as I would be in a high probability position!

Comment: You said it stuck to you. Sticking is binding and bound systems exhibit a non-zero ground-state energy.

Comment: That energy would be onky visible as kinetic energy to someone outside the frame I believe,  inside it that would be dissipated heat. Even if it is not, what do you mean to say? I would be in a frame with particle at rest at origin, if you are contradicting this please explain I am all ears!

Comment: A bound particle doesn't have a rest frame, it's wave function is a standing wave which means that it is made up of two components moving opposite to each other and reflecting off the binding potential. I have to say that I get the feeling you are trying to argue this on the basis of fuzzy word pictures without understanding the math. At some point the math is indispensable.

Comment: It is indeed true that I am less than incompetent in maths of this level, but I based my question on the intuition that if a particle nature does exist as there is a wave-particle duality and not just wave-wave function thing then simple arguments like what I put forward must be reasonable.

Answer (score 1):

In particle physics we continually go to the center of mass system for the interactions under study, because the mathematical expressions are simpler and Lorenz invariance assures that the results will be the same in whatever system one studies the interaction.

Suppose we have [an electron](http://teachers.web.cern.ch/teachers/archiv/hst2001/bubblechambers/Alison/index.html) in a bubble chamber.

[image: pimue]

This is a pion decaying into a muon and an electron, with missing two neutrinos, but we are interested in the electron. It leaves a track like a particle should, and this track are tiny bubbles from soft interactions/ionization  of the electron so it keeps losing energy to ionization and that is why it makes a spiral in the magnetic field that permeates the chamber. We can get its momentum at the point of the muon decay with good accuracy by considering the curvature in the beginning. This introduces a measurement error that is much larger than the heisenberg uncertainty principle (HUP) of the delta(x) of the muon-to-electron point with the delta(p) of our measurement, so even though we go to the center of mass of the electron , the measurement uncertainty will propagate on all the variables in the system, the momentum of the neutrinos and the muon in the center of mass system of the electron. All values will have a +/-delta to them, thus position and momentum are not known at the same time, because of measurement errors . The position of the electron has an error and thus even if we think we are at the electron center of mass there will be a measurement uncertainty at the decay point of the decaying muon and electron neutrino, and the momentum of the electron will be 0+/-delta(p) .

Suppose that we could measure all the bubbles to a very small accuracy and the curvature of the electrons to such a small accuracy. The HUP tells us that this is not possible because the wave nature of the probability distribution for the electron will limit the measured  values with a delta(x) and a delta(p). Thus in the center of mass of the electron the decay point will be uncertain and the 0 momentum of the electron will have a delta spread.

This would be true for a hypothetical free electron too at rest, the zero in x will have +/- delta(x) as well as the zero in momentum +/- delta(p) from the  HUP uncertainty.