# Does relativity violate uncertainty principle?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, special-relativity, electrons, relativity, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

Let us say I sit on an electron. According to me the electron is at rest. Also, I will know the position of the electron accurately as I can take the electron as the origin. So, I know both position and momentum of the electron accurately. But it violates the uncertainty principle. How is that possible

Comment: One can't "sit" on electrons, so it's not possible.

Comment: Relativity does not violate uncertainty principle but I can't tell you what part of your experiment is wrong

Comment: If you are sitting on it how would you know its velocity? To know its velocity you'd need another particle to see how it moves relatively to that particle, but remember that particle is governed by quantum mechanics.

Comment: Probably not.... I mean I, or someone else would have noticed, right guys?

Comment: Related (duplicate?): http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/111970/no-uncertainties-for-particles-in-their-own-frames

Answer (score 12):

If you say:

> According to me the electron is at rest.

that means you have measured the electron momentum to be zero, in which case the electron position is completely uncertain. So you can't be sitting on the electron. If you say:

> Let us say I sit on an electron.

that means you have measured its position precisely so you have no idea what its momentum is. So the electron can't be at rest wrt you.

So you start your question by assuming that you can violate the uncertainty principle then conclude that it violates the uncertainty principle.

Comment: Yes! I think your answer makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

Your question has several flaws.

First, you say the electron is at rest at the origin. As John Rennie noted, this implies that the position and momentum are both sharp, which contradicts the uncertainty principle. There is no such thing as an electron at rest at a particular point. An electron is described by a wave function spread over an extended region in both position and momentum space.

Second, the title to your question states something about relativity and the uncertainty principle, but your question does not explain this alleged connection.

Your question seems to indicate that you know nothing about quantum mechanics or relativity. I should recommend that you do some reading about both theories. There are many good books explaining relativity like "Special Relativity" by A. P. French. There are books explaining the formalism of quantum mechanics, although their explanations leave a lot to be desired, see "Quantum Mechanics: A Modern Development" by Ballentine.

Comment: by construction, anything at rest at the origine of a frame has a known position and a known null momentum. It's the only one ( so poor ) certainty

Comment: @igael: I have edited my answer to make it a bit clearer. There is no such thing as an electron at rest at the origin. An electron is described by a wave function with a finite spread over position and momentum.

Comment: it depends of the theory of the discussion. Anyway, setting a frame in a way compatible with the uncertainty theories is not trivial at all.

Comment: @igael: The principle arises in quantum mechanics. So if you want to understand it, you look at quantum mechanics. If you want to understand relativistic quantum theories, then you look at quantum field theory.

Comment: a duplicate [here](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/111970/no-uncertainties-for-particles-in-their-own-frames) . Each theory has its own formalism which induces not well known limits. But, we agree that the particles' clouds cannot be the mathematical dot of a frame origin in an operational quantum theory